# Change event handler on select with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with several selects like this:

```
<div class="forms">
  <div class="activity_form" id="activity_8">
    <select id="activity_projectuser_id" name="activity[projectuser_id]">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="activity_form" id="activity_9">
    <select id="activity_projectuser_id" name="activity[projectuser_id]">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have an event handler to retrieve the selected value, that only works for number `8`:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  $('#activity_8 #activity_projectuser_id').change(function() {
    console.log("yes!");
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

How can I change the event handler so it works on any `activity` id?

Comment: *"I have a page with several selects like this:"* Then you have an invalid page. You cannot use the same `id` (`activity_projectuser_id`) on more than one element.

Comment: I agree and I will do that, but the accepted answer perfectly answers my request on how to handle dynamic selects

Comment: John - If you want to match *all* of them like that, [Milind's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27274613/157247) is dramatically better, because in addition to working, it doesn't encourage keeping the invalid `id` values. (In my answer, I thought you wanted one specific one, based on the activity ID, but if you want all, Milind's shows the right way to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. you can target them based on their `name` instead:

```
$('.activity_form [name="activity[projectuser_id]"]').change(function() { //or $('.activity_form select')
  console.log("yes!");
});
```

Comment: Or even just `$('[name="activity[projectuser_id]"]')...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector

```
$('[name^="activity"]').change(function() { ... });
```

That will assume your name starts with `activity`. You could also use a wildcard `*` instead of `^` for contains activity.

Comment: I switched to name, care to remove your downvote? I originally thought he had the ids on the selects but it was on the parent div.

Comment: So this is effectively Milind's answer, now that you've edited it, except that it matches anything whose name starts with `activity` rather than specifically the elements the OP says he/she wants.